# Google Email Log Search API

Tags: google-admin-audit-api

We use google apps for work, and we want to be able to track our users gmail activities, like how many emails they receive, how many emails they reply & fail to reply.

I used to use this **Google Admin Reports API: Users Usage Report** to get the stats but the result is inaccurate, and it doesn't return the detailed message list.

The **Email Log Search** from Google admin console is exactly what I want, but I am not sure if there's an **Email Log Search API** available so we can loop through all our users and retrieve their email received/sent list?

If there isn't , what would be the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: It's not clear what your question actually is.

Comment: You can check this link https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/ , this API allows Google Apss Admin to audit users email,drafts, archived chats and download user's mailbox.

Comment: Were you able to find the API? We're looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

If you're just looking for email counts, I would use the Gmail API to do this (I use that currently for the same). You will not get email logs though, in case you're looking for details on potential delays / rejections /etc. I do not believe there is a Reports API section geared for this at the moment.